# Is it right to use nested master pages in this case?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm making a website which has different panels for various users. All these panels have some menu items which are different depending on the user logged on, except one item which is available in every panel for every user.
And also the page that is linked to this item is identical for every user.

Now my question is that how can I make this page to appear to every user while other menu items are shown along with this fixed menu item at the same time ?!

I used nested master pages, but I'm stuck somehow !

In my parent master page, I placed my fixed menu item and in the child master I placed the rest of the menu items for each panel. So now I have one parent master page and several child master pages each containing user's required menu items.

And this is the "I'm stuck" part! 
I don't know how to make the page that is going to be linked to the fixed menu item!
Since it should be available for every user ..., If I make content pages from child masters then I have to make this page several times ....

I don't know whether I made myself clear. If there is any ambiguity, please ask!

Comment: Is there any problem with just setting the link of the common menu item to the common page?

Comment: Instead of creating several child master pages have you considered using UserControl (.ascx page), than add this to the content page.

Comment: @Jaypal, I don't know what UserControl is and how to use it ! Could you explain more please?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET